# Retrieve data from a website-hadoop

Tags: hadoop, flume, bigdata

I am able to retrieve data\tweets from twitter using developer API in past.

Now I want to retrieve data from a website. Its not click-stream data but the actual data being updated in website. For example, I want to retrieve match details that are being updated daily in a cricket website like cricinfo etc.

Could someone help me how to do this.

Thanks,
Sree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://cricsheet.org/).  Probably you can also try using [RSS Feeds](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/rss/feeds_rss_cricket.html) for this purpose provided by espncricinfo.com.